# Cannot open R dataset of NSDUH from SAMHDA: RAM issues?

Tags: r, import, ram

I have downloaded the complete dataset in R format of the [National Survey on Drug Use and Health (NSDUH)](https://www.datafiles.samhsa.gov/dataset/nsduh-2002-2019-ds0001-nsduh-2002-2019-ds0001) provided by the [Substance Abuse and Mental Health Data Archive (SAMHDA)](https://www.datafiles.samhsa.gov/):

However, the file cannot be opened on my laptop. Does this depend on RAM limitations (my PC has 16 GB of RAM)?

If that's the case, how can I overcome this issue?

Comment: Looks like they also provide flat text files, try to import X number of rows for testing. `data.table::fread("file.txt", nrows=10)`

Comment: You might also want to look up `readr` as it can limit reading to specific columns.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have circumvented the problem by downloading and uploading data year-wise (eg https://www.datafiles.samhsa.gov/dataset/national-survey-drug-use-and-health-2020-nsduh-2020-ds0001 for 2020)